# what is the difference between 困惑 and 糊涂

Tags: difference

What is the difference between 困惑 and 糊涂 ?
Supposedly both mean "confused" but still is not clear in which situation each is to be used

Answer (score 5):

困惑 - Puzzled. A person can be very smart but be puzzled by a question.
糊塗 - Confused, mistaken. It generally indicates the state of mind of a person. An elderly person is more likely to get confused or mistakes A for B.

The dominating word in 困惑 is 惑, which means bewilderment or difficulty in choice of a small number of options. The word 或 means either. 困 means in a very tight spot without room to move around. The original meaning of 困 is a small hut. The 木 (wood) in a 口 means that there is no room for the wood. When a person is in a situation that is both bewildered and yet does not have much choice, this person is in a bewilderment.

糊塗 - Both words are significant in describing the statement of mind. The radical of 糊 is 米 (rice). When rice is cooked too much that it gets burned, it is 糊, then it's a mess. The radical of 塗 is 土 (dirt/earth). The original meaning of 涂 is that it was the name of a river. When water is over dirt, there is mud. The person's mind is muddled.

Answer (score 0):

困惑 = to confuse; be confused (by external elements)

糊涂 = being confused (internally)

- You can: "被這個問題困惑" (were confused by this question)(O)
- You can't: "被這個問題糊涂" (being internally confused by this question)(X)
- You could:  "做人糊涂" = live confusedly (O)
- You couldn't: "做人困惑"  = live a life to confuse/ to be confused (X)

Answer (score 0):

困惑 - bewildered, perplexed, confused, puzzled about something and not knowing what to do.

糊涂 - muddled; refers to the lack of clear mind, mixing and confusing things/persons.